# Injective object in small module category

Tags: abstract-algebra, exact-sequence, injective-module

Consider a ring $R$ and its module category $R-\mathrm{Mod}$. In a full exact subcategory $\cal{C}$ (whose exact sequences are exact sequences in $R-\mathrm{Mod}$), it is not necessary that an injective object in $\cal{C}$ is injective as an $R$-module.

**My question is:** Under what condition, the injective objects in $\cal{C}$ are injective $R$-modules?

Known example: $\cal{C}=$ cat of f.g. $R$-modules. But I want a more general criterion.